# Alto consumo de CPU de Rails al refrescar varias veces la página

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Actualmente mantengo una web desarrollada con Rails 4.2 y haciendo pruebas me he fijado que si pulso F5 repetidas veces para refrescar la página el consumo de CPU del servidor se dispara hasta llegar al 100%. Concretamente se crean 4 procesos ruby (¿uno por cada núcleo?) con un uso de CPU cercano al 100% y con un consumo de RAM de apenas el 3% cada uno.

No entiendo mucho de servidores, pero no me parece un comportamiento normal. He realizado esta prueba sobre otras webs de Internet y por mucho que pulse F5 es como si la última petición que hago cancelase el resto, mientras que en la web que mantengo parece como si el servidor atendiese todas las peticiones hasta el final, haciendo que la última de las peticiones tarde mucho más de lo normal en cargar la página.

Estoy seguro que tiene que ser un problema de configuración, pero no se muy bien por dónde empezar.

El sistema operativo del servidor es Ubuntu 16.04 y la web se ejecuta sobre un servidor Unicorn junto a Nginx 1.10.0.

**EDITO:**

Las pruebas las he realizado sobre el entorno de producción que corre sobre una instancia *Amazon EC2 m3.xlarge* (Intel Xeon E5-2670 v2 (Ivy Bridge) de 4 núcleos / 15GB RAM).

**EDITO 2:**

He seguido haciendo pruebas en un entorno de test algo más modesto que el de producción y revisando el log de Unicorn veo que si refresco la página 100 veces el servidor las procesa todas, haciendo que la última de ellas tarde muchísimo en completarse. En ocasiones hasta me ha saltado un error 503.

Sospecho que el error tiene que estar en la configuración de Nginx o de Unicorn. Debe de faltar algo para que en vez de procesar todas las peticiones las cancele y solo atienda la última.

Comment: Estas probando en un servidor local? o uno en cloud, cuales son las caracteristicas de hardware ?

Comment: Hola Joel, las pruebas las he hecho en el entorno de producción que corre sobre una instancia Amazon EC2 m3.xlarge.

Comment: Podrías probar a instalar un monitor para rails como newrelic y te podría dar alguna pista de donde se están causando esos usos de cpu tan intensos

Comment: Lo de instalar newrelic queda descartado por ahora, no depende de mi el pagar la licencia. De todas formas tengo localizado el problema. El problema es que al lanzar muchas peticiones simultaneas (pulsando repetidas veces F5, por ejemplo) Unicorn las procesa todas y esto hace que la última de las peticiones tarde muchísimo en completarse. En ocasiones hasta me ha saltado un error 503.